# Which Hindu Scriptures contain post Mahabharata historical events?

Tags: scripture, puranas, history

I'm searching for a list of all Hindu scriptures containing post Mahabharat historical accounts. So far, I only know that some Puranas, RigVedic accounts of Battle of Ten Kings, and a scripture known as [Rajtarangini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajatarangini).

I'm just searching for a list of scriptures which have historical information, not the actual content pinpointed, as has been asked in the other question.

Comment: Related or Possible duplicate of [Chronological orders of dynasties and kings after Mahabharata as per Puranas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20817/3500) and [Authentic sources of history after the Mahabharat war](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16107/3500)

Comment: I edited your title.  Check it if it is proper.

Comment: @The Destroyer I'm looking for a list of scriptures which contain historical information, not the list of kings or contents of the scriptures pinpointed.